# Keyboard in android is not showing up on selecting the input text area

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, android-softkeyboard

I'm using `TMPro.TMP_InputField` in the unity editor `(2018.3.6)`.

In the game, when I click on it, I was expecting a onscreen keyboard to pop up to enter text. But I got the following floating area to enter text. See below image.

[image]

Googling for a bit I found the following suggestions to resolve the same :

```
inputField.Select();
inputField.ActivateInputField();
TouchScreenKeyboard.Open("", TouchScreenKeyboardType.Default, false, false, true);
```

Even on adding this, it's still the same.
Can anyone help me out on this?